# Apex property side-effect

Tags: apex

Where is side-effect in this code from documentation?

```
public class componentController {
    public String selectedValue {
        get;
        set {
            editMode = (value != null);
            // Side effect here - don't do this!
            selectedValue = value;
        }
    }
    public Boolean editMode {get; private set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's setting a property, `editMode`, other than the named property for which this is a setter.

This behavior is not best practice and is likely to cause confusion; setters should not have this type of side effect.

I don't think it's a great example. The preferred implementation would just have the getter for  `editMode` infer its value from the other property.